# How to call stop to MediaElement after a set duration?

Tags: c#, wpf, mediaelement

I have added a media element to a WPF window that plays a gif file. But I'm not sure how to stop the gif playing after a set number of seconds.

In my current implementation the gif plays to instruct the user how to perform an action when the window is loaded but I don't want the gif to play in a loop, I would like to be able to stop the gif after a number of seconds.

Is it possible to achieve this with a media element?

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
      // set the phrases to listen for and start listening
      listener.Phrases = PhrasesTextBox.Text;
      listener.StartListening();

      gifMediaElement.Play();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to continue to use the `MediaElement` type, one method would be to use a `DispatcherTimer`.  You can set it to tick on a certain number of seconds and turn both the timer off and the MediaElement.  For example:

```
DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //...
    gifMediaElement.Play();
    timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
    timer.Start();
    timer.Tick += (o, args) =>
    {
        timer.Stop();
        gifMediaElement.Stop();
    };
    //...
```

Answer (score 2):

Try use [`AnimatedGIFControl`](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CSWPFAnimatedGIF-3029aeb9):

In WPF MediaElement could show animated GIF images with some less desirable limitations:

1. The Source property must be set with absolute path;
2. Play-back functionality is not supported by default;
3. Transparent pixels display as black.

Below is example of using `AnimatedGIFControl`:

**`XAML`**

```
<Window x:Class="CSWPFAnimatedGIF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CSWPFAnimatedGIF"
        Title="Animated GIF" Height="300" Width="300">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <local:AnimatedGIFControl x:Name="GIFCtrl"/>

        <Button x:Name="btnStart" Width="70" Height="30" Margin="50" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="1" Click="btnStart_Click">Start</Button>

        <Button x:Name="btnStop" Width="70" Height="30" Margin="50"
                HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Row="1" Click="btnStop_Click">Stop</Button>        
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**`Code-behind`**

```
public class AnimatedGIFControl : System.Windows.Controls.Image
{
    private Bitmap _bitmap; // Local bitmap member to cache image resource
    private BitmapSource _bitmapSource;
    public delegate void FrameUpdatedEventHandler();


    /// <summary>
    /// Delete local bitmap resource
    /// Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183539(VS.85).aspx
    /// </summary>
    [DllImport("gdi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool DeleteObject(IntPtr hObject);

    /// <summary>
    /// Override the OnInitialized method
    /// </summary>
    protected override void OnInitialized(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInitialized(e);
        this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(AnimatedGIFControl_Loaded);
        this.Unloaded += new RoutedEventHandler(AnimatedGIFControl_Unloaded);           
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Load the embedded image for the Image.Source
    /// </summary>

    void AnimatedGIFControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Get GIF image from Resources
        if (Properties.Resources.ProgressIndicator != null)
        {
            _bitmap = Properties.Resources.ProgressIndicator;
            Width = _bitmap.Width;
            Height = _bitmap.Height;

            _bitmapSource = GetBitmapSource();
            Source = _bitmapSource;  
        }             
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Close the FileStream to unlock the GIF file
    /// </summary>
    private void AnimatedGIFControl_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        StopAnimate();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Start animation
    /// </summary>
    public void StartAnimate()
    {
        ImageAnimator.Animate(_bitmap, OnFrameChanged);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Stop animation
    /// </summary>
    public void StopAnimate()
    {
        ImageAnimator.StopAnimate(_bitmap, OnFrameChanged);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Event handler for the frame changed
    /// </summary>
    private void OnFrameChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                               new FrameUpdatedEventHandler(FrameUpdatedCallback));
    }

    private void FrameUpdatedCallback()
    {
        ImageAnimator.UpdateFrames();

        if (_bitmapSource != null)
            _bitmapSource.Freeze();

        // Convert the bitmap to BitmapSource that can be display in WPF Visual Tree
        _bitmapSource = GetBitmapSource();
        Source = _bitmapSource;
        InvalidateVisual();
    }

    private BitmapSource GetBitmapSource()
    {
        IntPtr handle = IntPtr.Zero;                

        try
        {
            handle = _bitmap.GetHbitmap();
            _bitmapSource = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
                handle, IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty, BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
        }
        finally
        {
            if (handle != IntPtr.Zero)
                DeleteObject(handle);
        }

        return _bitmapSource;
    }
}
```

**`Code Logic`**

1. Use `ImageAnimator` to animates a GIF image that has time-based frames.
2. Render every frame of GIF image in another thread using `InvalidateVisual` method.
3. Derive from the `Image` control, in order to make it easy to use as Image control.
4. Dispose the dump resources to ensure the efficiency.